# Azure AD Domain Services can't be access

Tags: azure, service, dns, active-directory, azure-active-directory

So try to make it easy for you to understand my problem, I have a software that needs an AD to work. In the software installation I setup all the correct data for the AD and MS SQL Server so that this software can work.

Now I want to try to see if I can do this with Azure AD Domain Service. I don’t want to use a Virtual Machine in the Azure cloud, I want to use my own Virtual Machine in my own Datacenter.

The domain dns I got from Azure, xxxx.onmicrosoft.com I can't seem to be able to access. I try to ping it, I try to use the other address I can see below /home/all resources/public IP-address.

I also setup a secure LDAP. I created my own certificate via Powershell and I uploaded it so that now the secure LDAP is active. But still I can’t seem to get any access to the domain dns address. In the Azure AD I created several groups that I need for my software to work and also my own admin. If I use the address myapps.microsoft.com and use the admin I can access that, and I can see the groups that I created.

But still I don’t know how to get access to the AD, I would be very happy if anyone could try to steer me in the right direction.

Thanks

Comment: If you want to integrate your own machine or VM with AD DS, you need to set up VPN to the VNet.

Comment: As from now, I know that this is a little bit more complicated then I thought from start. But I will close it, even though there is no solution here.